# Tools to control, edit, or emit the LC_UUID of a dylib?

Tags: ios, build, linker, dylib, bitcode

I'm producing dylibs with embedded bitcode and using the `-bitcode-symbol-map` flag to specify an output directory where files of the form `UUID.bcsymbolmap` get produced. I'd like to teach my build system about those `bcsymbolmap` files so I can install and package them, but it is hard to do so since the output name for the file is determined by the `LC_UUID` value in the dylib which seems to be determined by `ld`. It seems I have two choices:

- Find a way to explicitly set the `LC_UUID` of the dylib when building it, so that I can predict the output name of the `bcsymbolmap` file.
- Specify a well known name for the `bcsymbolmap` file (the `-bitcode-symbol-map` option does support this) which does not contain the UUID, and then at install time, figure out the `LC_UUID` of the associated dylib and rename the `bcsymbolmap` file appropriately.

However, I don't see either a linker flag that will let me specify the `LC_UUID` of the library when building it, or a tool to let me change it after the fact (thinking here of something like `install_name_tool`), nor do I see a utility that will easily give me back the `LC_UUID` of a given library (to do the needed renaming of the `bcsymbolmap` file), short of parsing the output of `otool -l`, which seems fragile and unpleasant.

I'd prefer to keep my options limited to things that ship with XCode. Does anyone know of tools to easily inject, edit, or emit the `LC_UUID` for a dylib?

Comment: To clarify, I'm *not* using the XCode build system to here, I'm using a different build system, say, CMake or SCons. So suggestions on how to configure an XCode project to do this won't help. I'm looking for command line tools that can be invoked from my build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something slightly better than parsing `otool -l` output: running `dwarfdump -u` on the target will list the UUIDs:

```
$ dwarfdump -u build/libfoo.dylib
UUID: BF8FAFCC-5B1F-3FC8-B2AF-FCDA16609D71 (arm64) build/libfoo.dylib
```

It still isn't ideal, but at least is trivial to parse with `awk` or similar.

Apple engineers, if anyone ever sees this, it would be very build system friendly to add an option to `ld` to explicitly set the `LC_UUID` at build time. The flag `-no_uuid` already exists, it would seem easy to add a `-uuid` flag that took a UUID as an argument and used that instead of generating one.